# Making a javascript button to work

Tags: javascript

- Was informed to ask this question here.

My Question is how do I get this to work. One image with background and two buttons which are click-able.

I have made up some javascript codes to try and make them function the way I need them to, but can't get it the way I need them to work out.

What I need is to get this code to work with an image

Javascript code:

```
function NewGame() {
document.forms[0].reset();
location.reload();
}
```

Html code:

```
<input type=button name=newgamebutton value="Restart" onClick="NewGame();">
```

Restart Button

How to make it when you click on the restart button it will display this image which will be slice into two part a yes and no image.

http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/1061/nnbo.jpg

Two slice buttons

When you click Restart a popup box will trigger a yes/no modal question and if you click yes restarts game and when you click no it goes back where you left off on the game.

Comment: I get a -1 for asking for help

Comment: What have you actually tried? The code you have posted just resets the forms and reloads the URL.

Comment: yes but i dont know how to code the background and the yes and no image buttons and the popup box.